# Price range in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller

```
$scope.details =
    [
        {
            "Title": "General Admission",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 50,
            "NonMemberPrice": 80
        },
        {
            "Title": "Special Event",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 100,
            "NonMemberPrice": 130
        },
        {
            "Title": "Birthday Party",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 160,
            "NonMemberPrice": 200
        },
        {
            "Title": "Education",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 220,
            "NonMemberPrice": 250
        },
        {
            "Title": "Donation",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 100,
            "NonMemberPrice": 165
        },
        {
            "Title": "Animal Adoption",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 180,
            "NonMemberPrice": 260
        },
        {
            "Title": "Retail",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 210,
            "NonMemberPrice": 270
        },
        {
            "Title": "Product",
            "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
            "MemberPrice": 250,
            "NonMemberPrice": 300
        }
    ];
```

This is my HTML page

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Select Price Range</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-options="price for price in priceRange.Min" ng-model="selectedPrice"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I want to do is that, I want to bind the price ranges in 'selectedPrice'. For example 0-100,101-200,201-300 ,and the minimum and maximum value in the price range should be present in the "$scope.details" either memberprice or nonmemberprice.

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly what you want to appear in the `<select>` box, so that it matches the data in your controller?

Comment: I want the price range to appear in the select , like 50-100 , 101-150 , 151-200 , the minimum (50) and maximum (200) should be from $scope.details (Memberprice,NonMemberPrice). Just to filter some tickets based on this price range.

Comment: I would just put the ranges in the options themselves.  Do you have a reason for not wanting to do this?  Even if you need the separate points of data, you could add a function to your controller which transforms the raw data into ranges.

Comment: The reason i don't want to do this is , The Json object may vary, for example the minimum price could be from 100, in such a situation if i just put the range from 0-50 there will not be any product in that price range and that should not happen..... That's the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function calculates min and max and determines the ranges based on the details. 
Working example is available in below plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Xops04bg58MT1vz8c4gR?p=preview

```
$scope.priceRanges = function() {
    var ranges = [],
      min,
      max,
      interval = 50;

    if (!$scope.details || !$scope.details.length) {
      return ranges;
    }

    min = $scope.details[0].MemberPrice;
    max = min;

    angular.forEach($scope.details, findMinMax);

    min = min - (min % interval);
    max = max - (max % interval) + interval;

    $scope.name = min + ' : ' + max;

    for (var i = min; i < max; i += interval) {
      if (i === min) {
        ranges.push(i + ' - ' + (i + interval));
      } else {
        ranges.push((i + 1) + ' - ' + (i + interval));
      }
    }

    return ranges;

    function findMinMax(detail) {
      if (min > detail.MemberPrice) {
        min = detail.MemberPrice;
      }
      if (min > detail.NonMemberPrice) {
        min = detail.NonMemberPrice;
      }
      if (max < detail.MemberPrice) {
        max = detail.MemberPrice;
      }
      if (max < detail.NonMemberPrice) {
        max = detail.NonMemberPrice;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to this.

```
<select ng-model="selectedPrice"               
    ng-options="price as (price.MemberPrice + ': ' + price.NonMemberPrice) for price in details"
    class="form-control" ></select>
```

Here is the fiddle:https://plnkr.co/edit/zeAFT6GjCmrwfOzNHdtC?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.details = [{
    "Title": "General Admission",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 51,
    "NonMemberPrice": 80
  }, {
    "Title": "Special Event",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 100,
    "NonMemberPrice": 130
  }, {
    "Title": "Birthday Party",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 160,
    "NonMemberPrice": 200
  }, {
    "Title": "Education",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 220,
    "NonMemberPrice": 250
  }, {
    "Title": "Donation",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 100,
    "NonMemberPrice": 165
  }, {
    "Title": "Animal Adoption",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 180,
    "NonMemberPrice": 260
  }, {
    "Title": "Retail",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 210,
    "NonMemberPrice": 270
  }, {
    "Title": "Product",
    "Image": "/images/img3.jpg",
    "MemberPrice": 250,
    "NonMemberPrice": 312
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Select Price Range</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select ng-model="selectedPrice"               
    ng-options="price as (price.MemberPrice + ': ' + price.NonMemberPrice) for price in details"
    class="form-control" ></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my code also work please see in the fiddle https://plnkr.co/edit/Xops04bg58MT1vz8c4gR?p=preview

Comment: You have provided the wrong plunker url, that is mine ;-)

Comment: i mistakenly edited your fiddle but code is mine :).Here is my Plunker Url
https://plnkr.co/edit/zeAFT6GjCmrwfOzNHdtC?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115370/discussion-between-zeeshan-qurban-and-muthukannan-kanniappan).

Comment: its happen by mistake now my code is added in snippet.please see

Answer (score 1):

For binding and showing priceRanges you could use this code;

```
<select ng-model="selectedPrice"               
        ng-options="(i.MemberPrice +'-'+ i.NonMemberPrice) 
                 as (i.MemberPrice +'-'+ i.NonMemberPrice) 
                 for i in details" ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. For this first you need to find the price range.

As per your json, its a fixed thing that the `MemberPrice` would always be less than the `NonMemberPrice`.

So a function such as

```
$scope.MinMax = findMinMax($scope.details);
    function findMinMax(x){
        var min = x[0].MemberPrice;
        var max = x[0].NonMemberPrice;
        for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
            if(x[i].MemberPrice<min){
                min = x[i].MemberPrice;
            }

            if(x[i].NonMemberPrice>max){
                max = x[i].NonMemberPrice;
            }
        }
        return {'min':min,'max':max};
    }
```

could get you your min and max in $scope and there by in view.

Now all you need is a filter such as below.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, min, max) {
    min = parseInt(min);
    max = parseInt(max);
    for (var i=min; i<=max; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
With the repeat used like this:

<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
  do something
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZVp/1/